# Why this function in c is giving unexpected results?

Tags: c

I'm learning C function construction and I'm trying to make an exponent function with two arguments: base & exponent.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int power(int a,int b){

    int c;
    int i;
    c=1;

    for(i=1;i<=b;++i){
        c=c*a;
    }
    return c;
}

int main(){

    int nice=power(5,20);
    printf("answer =%d , and size is=%d ", nice, sizeof(nice));
    return 0;
}
```

When I execute the program, it gives me the following output:

> answer =1977800241 ,and size is=4

EDIT:
But when I execute `power(5,2)`, it gives a perfect result of 25.

Comment: 5^20 is a big number, it does not fit into an `int`.

Comment: What value are you expecting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is having integer overflow. You have to use `unsigned long long` or `long long` .

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef long long ll;
ll power(ll a,ll b){

ll c,i;
c=1;

for(i=1;i<=b;++i){
    c=c*a;
}
return c;
}

int main(){

ll nice=power(5,20);
printf("answer =%lld , and size is=%lld ", nice, sizeof(nice));
return 0;
}
```

### NOTE:

You will have a good idea about this -> read this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/199333/how-to-detect-integer-overflow-in-c-c).

### QUESTION-2: WHat happens for a=5 b=100

Then you have to write your custom function for manipulating the multiplications. Use int `arr[100]` to hold the digits of the large number and then multiply it accordingly.C/C++ doesn't provide anything like `BIgInt` of `Java`, you have to build it.

Comment: Thanks that worked. But i have a question . The compiler is throwing a warning saying ""unknown conversion type character 'l' in format. "" But it still works. Also what about more bigger numbers? like base=100 & exponent = 20?

Comment: @coderredoc Why do you `typedef` the `long long int` datatype?

Comment: splotz90.: I actually use this alot in competitive programming..habit I will say